# Запятая при слове «считайте»

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: «Дорог в селе считайте, что нет»... Как бы хочется назвать «считайте» вводным в данном случае. Или я не права?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Дорог в селе считайте что нет.***

Думаю, знаков здесь тоже нет, это **устойчивое выражение**. Возможная замена: *Дорог в селе **практически** нет.*

Вводное слово можно изъять из предложения, но здесь этого сделать нельзя, тогда получится: *Дорог в селе что нет.*

**Примеры из Нацкоруса:**

Развлечений в те годы в Якутске **не было считай что** никаких. [Д. И. Саврасов. (2003-2008)]

Летом Вика в лагере, а это **считай что** тишина и одиночество. [Екатерина Завершнева. (2012)]

Сам Глеб был **считай что** чист. [Ольга Новикова. 2012]

За меру вина. Ну, в общем, **считай что** даром. [А. А. Уткин. (2010)]

Comment: А если так? *Считайте(,) что нет дорог в селе. Считайте(,) что дорог в селе нет.*

Comment: Прочитайте http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137, пункт 2. Там  одно и то же содержание представлено в двух формах (с запятой и без запятой). Извините за краткость, я не очень люблю возвращаться к темам, заданным ранее.