Пунктуация в предложении: Если проснулся ночью(,) считай(,) пропал
Вопрос по недавней теме, к которой был проявлен несомненный ИНТЕРЕС.
Так почему же  в заданном там предложении не может быть вводного слова, а в других случаях — пожалуйста! Нужен бы анализ. Это вопрос прежде всего к участникам разговора (4 ответа).
Рассмотрим предложения, которые помогут разобраться в теме:
(1) Если проснулся ночью(,) считай(,) пропал.
(2) Если проснулся ночью (,) считай(,) ЧТО пропал.
(3) Если проснулся ночью (,) ТО считай(,) ЧТО пропал.
Сообщение можно оформить по-разному. Какие  варианты вы считаете правильными? А также какой вариант  будет наилучшим?


Рассмотрим оформление вариантов:

(1) Если проснулся ночью, /  считай, пропал.
Вариант Справочной службы, формально он верен. СПП, две предикативные основы, вводное слово считай между придаточной и главной частью.
Стиль разговорный, но интонация недостаточно невыразительная.
(2) Если проснулся ночью, считай, что пропал.
СПП, три предикативные основы, считай — сказуемое в главной части.
(3) Если проснулся ночью, // то считай, что пропал.
Аналогичный вариант, но предложение делится на два блока  при использовании двойного союза.

Я бы записала так: Если проснулся ночью — считай что пропал.
Или лучше как БСП: Проснулся ночью — считай что пропал.

Здесь считай что — устойчивое сочетание (= все равно что). СПП, две предикативные основы, тире как неосновной знак при наличии паузы (подчеркивание взаимообусловленности предложений).

Материалы по теме

Карта слов "считать что"
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471848/Запятая-при-слове-считайте
Управление в русском языке (Розенталь)
СЧИТАТЬ [делать какое-л. заключение о ком-чем-л.; признавать; полагать] кем-чем / (разг.) за кого-что. Считать человека погибшим; Если же ты выйдешь за Лужина, я тотчас же перестаю тебя сестрой считать (Дост.); Считать эти действия своим долгом; ...Скоро будет прямо за последнего нищего считать (М.-С.); Можно быть очень умным человеком и не понимать поэзии, считать её за вздор (Бел.).

Как известно из правил Розенталя, устойчивые сочетания с подчинительными союзами  используются в значении одного слова, но в этом случае они должны быть достаточно компактными, чтобы вписаться в фонетическую структуру предложения. В предыдущей теме придаточное не отвечало этим требованиям, но это же сообщение можно было записать иначе, в том числе с союзом ЧТО: Если  так скажут — считайте что похвалили.

"Считал, считать" у Розенталя сочетание с существительными в косвенном падеже: считать человека(В.п.), считать сестрой(Т.п.), считать действия(В.п., считать друзей), считать нищего(В.п), считать её(В.п.), - с глаголами примеров нет. У вас в предложении глагол. Если бы было "считай пропавшим(человеком)" - то да, но тогда и подчинительный союз "что" бы отпал за ненадобность.

Из словаря:   1. СЧИТАТЬ,  нсв.   7. (св. счесть и посчитать). КОГО-ЧТО. Расценивать, воспринимать каким-л. образом. С. кого-л. счастливым. С. кого-л. ненормальным, фантазёром, идеалистом. С. кого-л. образцом, примером для подражания. С. что-л. своим долгом, своей обязанностью. С. что-л. вздором, нелепицей. Перестать с. кого-л. умным, честным, порядочным человеком. Считаю за счастье, за честь познакомиться с вами. // с придат. дополнит. Иметь какое-л. мнение, полагать. Считаю, что ты не прав.

Все так, просто русские глаголы - это не понятия указывающие на предметы или явления, а слова иного рода, поэтому глаголы под определения "кого-что" не попадают никак. Считать (что) пропал - не корректно, считать пропавшим - да. Если глаголы перейдут в разряд существительных, тогда граница будет окончательно стёрта и получится полный рунглиш.

Пропал вышел из дома на улицу.) Не, ну конечно можно придумать такой язык)

Я не соглашусь.
"Считай" с глаголами всегда пишется через знак препинания.
Если же считай употреблено с существительном в косвенном падеже(родительном, творительном, винительном), то есть считай "кого, чего, что, кем, чем?".

Смотри своей жене-то в зубы, да считай года, а наши еще не считаны.

Форма согласованного существительного в именительном падеже в литературе классической отсутствует, только в современной бывает, когда "считай" не обособлено от существительного в И.п.

Успел дойти, не отморозив пальцы, считай счастливец.

Но я считаю это ошибкой согласования - считай счастливцЕМ.
А в данных предложениях считай обособляется 99.9%:
"Мы с ним считай (считай что) земляки ((почти)); Рублей сто считай заработали."
Мы с ним, считай, земляки =/= считай нас земляками, поэтому, конечно, обособление должно быть. Рублей сто, считай, заработали - конфликт разноосновных глаголов: ты - считай, мы - заработали.
В предложении -
Если проснулся ночью, считай, пропал.
"Считай" - вводное, если по-простому. Однако фраза разговорная и малосодержательная, скорее это обрубец от: ночью не просыпайся, считай часы, иначе пропадешь, - то есть в такой фразе нет недосказанностей, которая есть даже без "считай" в первоначальной фразе, несмотря на вроде бы обнадёживающее "если", так как предложение полностью лишено деталей и не выглядит как внятно выраженная мысль.
Почему создаётся желание согласовать существительное в И.п., сложно сказать, но вот как пишет Толстой:

Взяв заповедь: не прелюбодействуй, имеющую целью то, чтобы люди своими
половыми отношениями не вредили друг, другу, Иисус говорит: не считай
похоть(В.п.) плотскую хорошим делом.

Похоть в винительном падеже, потому что "плотскУЮ", была бы в именительном, то было бы "плоскАЯ". Либо, вторая логика, - не считай делом(Т.п.). То есть даже если фразу урезать до "не считай делом", то это была бы часть фразы, существительное в творительном падеже согласовано с существительным в винительном. То есть полная схема подобных предложений: "считай" сущ. или им.(В.п.) сущ.(Т.п.):

Если же ты выйдешь за Лужина, я тотчас же перестаю тебя сестрой
считать (Дост.)

Считать тебя(В.п.), считать сестрой(Т.п.).
Возможно, создается путаница из-за схожести форм винительного и именительного падежей во множественном числе счётных слов, однако:

Считай капли, давай рубли... Считай деньги.

Это винительный падеж, потому что считай каплю, а не считай "капля"(иначе придётся как минимум ставить кавычки), потому что "вроде как капля".
А вот как Горький решает эту сложность, усиливая разрыв между фразами:

Губернских-то городов — считай — десятка четыре, а уездных — тысячи,
поди-ка!


Все варианты верны. Вводное слово выделяется с двух сторон запятыми. Хотя предложение носит явно разговорный характер, поэтому думаю, первый вариант более естественный.
Вот говорится в Русской грамматике-80
Словоформа считай (считай что) (прост.) вносит значение приближения к истинности: Мы с ним считай (считай что) земляки ((почти)); Рублей сто считай заработали.

Спасибо, Серж.  Сообщение действительно имеет разговорный характер, но такой вариант даже сложнее оформить, чем книжную речь. Упрощенный синтаксис часто сопровождается более сильными знаками, такими как тире. Предложение (1) из Грамоты.ру, именно там упомянуто вводное слов в СЛОЖНОМ предложении. Мне оно показалось невыразительным, хотя формально возразить нечего. Но вот появляется изъяснительный союз ЧТО, и вводное слово уже под большим вопросом: сказуемое это или все же вводное? В двух ответах участники уверенно называют сказуемое. Но, может, исключения возможны? Об этом надо подумать

https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=считай&mode=spravka#:~:text=Считай%20--%20вводное%20слово%2C%20выделяется,проснулся%20ночью%2C%20считай%2C%20пропал.

Да, я видел ответ-вопрос на Грамоте. ру.

Шарон, ссылку не получается дать. Вечером зайду через компьютер, постараюсь дать ссылку.
